# MSSQL Database Create Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
use [BandivanKat]
go
alter procedure proc1
(
@ID int,
@katnatvutyun float,
@yuxaynutyun float
)
as
declare @tari  int
declare @amis  int
declare @countamis int=0
if  @ID in( select number from Animals where age_Group='կով' and  isdeleted=0)  and @ID  not in (select id from katnatvutyun)
insert into katnatvutyun values (@ID,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
set @tari=YEAR(GETDATE())
set @amis=MONTH(GETDATE())

if  @amis=1 begin UPDATE katnatvutyun  set hunvar=(select isnull(hunvar,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun    
    if (select isnull(hunvar,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if  @amis=2 begin   UPDATE katnatvutyun set petrvar=(select isnull(petrvar,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun 
if (select isnull(petrvar,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=3 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set mart=(select isnull(mart,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun 
if (select isnull(mart,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=4 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set april=(select isnull(april,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun   
if (select isnull(april,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=5 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set majis=(select isnull(majis,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(majis,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=6 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set hunis=(select isnull(hunis,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun

if (select isnull(hunis,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end 
if @amis=7 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set hulis=(select isnull(hulis,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(hulis,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=8 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set ogostos=(select isnull(ogostos,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(ogostos,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=9 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set september=(select isnull(september,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(september,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=10 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set hoktember=(select isnull(hoktember,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(hoktember,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=11 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set noyember=(select isnull(noyember,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(noyember,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
if @amis=12 begin  UPDATE katnatvutyun set dektember=(select isnull(dektember,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)+@katnatvutyun
if (select isnull(dektember,0) from katnatvutyun where ID=@ID)>0 set @countamis=@countamis+1
end
update katnatvutyun set summilk=(isnull(hunvar,0)+ isnull(petrvar,0)+isnull(mart,0)+isnull(majis,0)+isnull(hunis,0)+isnull(hulis,0)+isnull(ogostos,0)+isnull(september,0)+isnull(hoktember,0)+isnull(noyember,0)+isnull(dektember,0))  where ID=@ID
update katnatvutyun set avgmilk=summilk/@countamis  where ID=@ID 
if @yuxaynutyun <>'' UPDATE katnatvutyun set yuxaynutyun = @yuxaynutyun 
go
```

У меня вот такой код в БД но не понимаю почему не работает возвращает целочисленное значение место того что бы записать данные в таблицу

Таблица вот такая

```
create table katnatvutyun
(
   ID integer primary key ,
hunvar float,
petrvar float,
mart float,
april float,
majis float,
hunis float,
hulis float,
ogostos float,
september float,
hoktember float,
noyember float,
dektember float,
summilk float,   
avgmilk float
)
```

первые 12 столбцы это название месяцев,в каждом месяце вводится одно значение процедура определяет какой месяц и значение  записывает в нужном столбце,в **summilk** считывается общая сумма,а **avgmilk** определяет сколько столбцов было записан значения и считывает для них средное значение,процедура принимает три параметра
 1. номер животного для которого должно сделать запись
 2. значение на месяца (одно число например 50)
 3. просто характеризующая число
третий параметр записывается в этом столбце

```
alter table katnatvutyun ADD yuxaynutyun float
```

Comment: чего возвращает то?

Comment: *"Йогурт без даты"*, что это. добавьте *поясниловку*

Comment: @Dmitry возвращает 0

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость попробую дать *пару* рекомендаций:  1. Для именования методов/переменных и т.п. использовать общепринятый язык(например английский, если с ним *туго* то поступать как я - translate.google.ru например); 2. Приведенный код это конечно здорово, вот только он понятен только Вам(в нем конечно можно разобраться но мне например лень), было бы лучше если бы Вы описали структуру таблицы, привели пример данных, и что Вы хотите получить в итоге. так было бы проще тем кто хочет помочь и Вы получите ответ быстрее, а может Вам подсказали бы как лучше сделать иначе/правильнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-видимому, ноль это *rows affected* (т.к. нет `set nocount on`).
Значит, не произошло вставки и обновления данных.

Возможно дело в условии

```
@ID in( select number from Animals where age_Group='կով' and  isdeleted=0)
```

Попробуйте поменять

```
age_Group='կով'
```

на

```
age_Group=N'կով'
```